# Reason for the 2021 moderator election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

There are three possible reasons for having the moderators election this year (with 3 positions to fill):

1. 3 moderators from the current team have decided to step down (for reasons that I consider personal and about which I am not asking);
2. 3 new moderator positions are created, in addition to the already existing ones, and nobody steps down;
3. a mix of the above: at least one moderator stepping down and at least one new position being created.

> Which of the above is the reason for the current election?

(I have browsed the Meta posts from the last month in search for an answer, but I haven't found anything, assuming I haven't overlooked anything relevant.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was covered in comments elsewhere. No moderator is planning to step down.

> @SamHopkins None of the current moderators are expected to step down. Some of the moderators have reduced their activity on the user-visible end of things, but none have expressed the desire to fully step down. ([François G. Dorais](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees#comment25278_4926))