# Upcoming election announcement (2022)

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

It has been quite some time since the last moderator election, and we decided that it would be a good idea to hold one soon.

This is just a preliminary announcement to let you know that this is going to happen. In due time more significant announcements will come, the usual threads calling for questions and nominations, etc.

But for now, this is something for you to keep in mind.

**Timeline for the election:**

1. Nominations will open on the 19th of September, 2022.
2. The election will begin on the 26th of the same month.
3. The election will end on 4th of October of the same year.

As of now, we will be adding **one moderator** to the team this time.

Comment: Do I have right that since the last election, two moderators have stepped down, Francois Dorais and David Zureick-Brown?

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: I don't know from which election to this date but I also remember other two persons that were moderators of Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @NoahSnyder On January 27, François G. Dorais [edited his name from the post about history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/754/18). Looking at the Wayback Machine, I see [both of them in May 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210522035110/https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=moderators) - and neither of them in [July 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220731011049/https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: @Martin: David Zureick-Brown stepped down on 23 June, 2021; Scott Morrison stepped down on 22 July, 2021; François G. Dorais on 27 January 2022.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: See the above comment. It is proof that time is not linear for me and that I cannot count more than "this" many.

Comment: Maybe we should have a post with suggestions for nominees, like this one last year: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees?rq=1

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi There is now the following post: [Nominating other community members](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5457).